# Does WP identify plugin by plugin name or plugin_basename?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I see from the activation link, wordpress is using the plugin's dir. Also, when many plugins use add_action to hook on activation, they use

```
add_action('activate_' . plugin_basename(), 'name_activation');
```

If the plugin dir is word/ , the plugin name is Press, then, this will be:

```
add_action('activate_word', 'press_activation'');
```

So, WP identify the plugin as "word" or "press" ?
I know that by using 'activate_word', WP gets to know which file to activate. I also tested that the "Press" got activated and running. But, is there any potential trouble to consider?

Answer (score 1):

Plugins are identified by the path to the file containing the plugin headers.  For instance the debug bar plugin would be identified as: `debug-bar/debug-bar.php`

#### See [`activate_plugin`](http://queryposts.com/function/activate_plugin/)

To add an action on activation you need to register the hook using [`register_activation_hook( $file, $function )`](http://queryposts.com/function/register_activation_hook/)

example: `register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'activation_function' );`

Comment: So, beside showing up on the plugins list, the plugin name doesn't make any sense to WP?